# Formula to get last thursday not including today

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use the following formula to get last thursdays date. However if I use it on a thursday it will get todays date.

Is there anyway to get previous thursday excluding today?ie Today is the 9th, it is returing the 9th, I would like it to return the 2nd.

`=TODAY()-MOD(WEEKDAY(TODAY())+2,7)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract 1 from both `TODAY()` to pretend it is yesterday:

```
=TODAY()-1-MOD(WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)+2,7)
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @Binggo_MSFT's answer I put together this formula which will **not** fail on today's date:

```
=A1-WEEKDAY(A1-5)
```

But why the magic "5"?? Because we want the *previous* Thursday for which `WEEKDAY(a_Thursday)=5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to the formula below:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)-3
```

[image]

Comment: We are interpreting the question differently.  I believe that the OP is looking for the most recent Thursday.  On Friday, the most recent Thursday is yesterday (today minus 1).  On Friday, your formula returns today **minus 8**; i.e., the *previous **week’s*** Thursday.